# How to save remember password against 2 fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a login form :

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="UserName" placeholder='Username' />
</div>
<div>
    <Select id="UserName" placeholder='UserType'>
      <Option>Type1</Option>
      <Option>Type2</Option>
      <Option>Type3</Option>
    </Select>
</div>**strong text**
<div>
    <input type="password" id="Password" placeholder='Password' />
</div>
<div>
   <button class="loginSubmit">Login</button>
</div>
```

When I login, the browser asks whether I want to "remember password". The password is saved against UserName only in browser.

But my password is depends on both UserName and UserType and I want to save the password against UserName + UserType.

And when UserName type and select UserType then only password stored in browser occur on Password field.

Comment: oh dear god, please dont store a password in the browser...

Comment: @leemo: you are getting me wrong. I am talking about browsers default functionality 'Remember Password'.

Comment: I don't think so. It is a browser functionality. And hope there is no plugin also to help you. How far I understand you are testing some of your development work. And you don't want to put the username and password repeatedly

Comment: I can see in browser only 2 fields are saved username and password.